# Ajax Jquery CORS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

Hi everyone i'am fighting and searching solutions about this from 3 days. I have a problem getting data from sharethis.com RESTapi. I am working with jQuery and Laravel 5.2. I want to get values from this json: http://rest.sharethis.com/v1/count/urlinfo?url=http://www.sharethis.com but i'am very frustated trying a lot of methods and functions. My actual code is this:

```
function setHeader(xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
}
$.ajax({
url: 'http://rest.sharethis.com/v1/count/urlinfo?url=http://www.sharethis.com',
type: 'GET',
beforeSend: setHeader,
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
success: function() { alert("Success"); },
error: function() { alert('Failed!'); }
});
```

This request always return "Failed!". I understand a little what CORS means but on practice i can't make it work. Any ideas? Thanks..

Comment: *" I understand CORS"* ... clearly you don't, those headers can't be set in request, they have to be set server side

Comment: Hi @charlietfl i put this on first line of my php file: <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?> but not make any change... any idea?

Comment: @Francisco This one header is not enough. You need `Allow-Headers` and `Allow-Methods` as well.

Comment: But you don't control sharethis.com. Request isn't going to your server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you actually don't understand CORS :)

These headers have to be present in the response, not in the request.

The server has to provide them.

The server has to agree.

The URL you provided doesn't have CORS headers so you can't fetch it via AJAX unless you modify the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code with XMLHttpRequest to get data

```
 var url = "http://rest.sharethis.com/v1/count/urlinfo?url=http://www.sharethis.com";

 var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);

 xhr.setRequestHeader(

'X-Custom-Header', 'value');

xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.onload = function () {

            if (this.status === 200) {

                console.log(xhr);
            }

};

xhr.send();
```

And there is the function to check if the url support CORS

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) 
{

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
   // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
   xhr.open(method, url, true);

   console.log("for chrome/fir");
 } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
   // XDomainRequest for IE.
   xhr = new XDomainRequest();
   xhr.open(method, url);

   console.log("ie");
 } else {
   // CORS not supported.
   xhr = null;
   console.log("not supported");
 }
 return xhr;
}
```

hope it helps, regards

Comment: Hi thanks for you help but the console still saying: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://rest.sharethis.com/v1/count/urlinfo?url=http://www.sharethis.com. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.