# CORS not working with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I have the below code in WCF RESTful Service

```
public EmployeeJSON GetEmployeeJSON(string id)
    {
        List<EmployeeJSON> employees = new List<EmployeeJSON>()
        {
             new EmployeeJSON() {Name="Sumanth",Id=101,Salary=5000.00 },
             new EmployeeJSON() {Name="Ehsan",Id=102,Salary=6000.00 },
        };

        var Employee = (from x in employees
                        where x.Id.ToString() == id
                        select x);


        return Employee.FirstOrDefault() as EmployeeJSON;
    }
```

The below is the declaration of the RESTful Service

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetJson/{id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
EmployeeJSON GetEmployeeJSON(string id);
```

When I execute the below URL in the browser

```
http://localhost:1249/Service1.svc/GetJson/101
```

I get the result as below

```
{"GetEmployeeJSONResult":{"Id":101,"Name":"Sumanth","Salary":5000}}
```

But when I am calling from jQuery, the code is going to error block and displays empty message

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    });

    var GetJson = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:1249/Service1.svc/GetJson/101",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var result = data.GetEmployeeJSONResult;
                var id = result.Id;
                var name = result.Name;
                var salary = result.Salary;
                $('#jsonData').html('');
                $('#jsonData').append('<table border="1"><tr><th>Employee Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Salary</th></tr><tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + salary + '</td></tr></table>');

            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

The below is the code, I placed in the web.config of WCF RESTful Service

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can your maybe also add the whole data of the `xhr` variable (from your error block)?

Comment: Please consult the spec and the hundreds of articles on this. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is just **one** header you have to include, there are usually others as well.

Comment: Open browser dev console and see what exactly request and response are. My wild guess would be response will be 405 method not allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197460/ajax-jquery-cors-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your WEB API to use CORS by adding next lines of code to your Startup class:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
var enableCors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(enableCors);
```

*where `app` is `IAppBuilder` and `config` is `HttpConfiguration`

Comment: Is it possible to add like this in web.config file `<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>`.

Comment: For me setting in web.config file as comment above is not working.

Comment: You need to configure WEB API, adding headers attribute is not enough.

Comment: I am not using WEB API at all. I am using a simple web application that calls the service. Also when I try to debug using developer tools, I am getting 404 error as `Failed to load http://localhost:1249/Service/Service1.svc/GetJson: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404`. Here extra `Service` is added in the URL while throwing the error in Dev Tools of Chrome.